# KDE - wrong screen resolution

Tags: display, linux-mint, resolution, kde

I just installed Linux Mint 17.2 with KDE. The default screen resolution is 1280x1024. I cannot change it to 1920x1080, which is the resolution of my monitor.

[image]

Is this normal? Is there any way to change it?

Edit:

I have the following dmesg outputs

```
inf3rno@inf3rno-EP43T-USB3:~ > dmesg | grep driver
[    0.068000] Performance Events: PEBS fmt0+, 4-deep LBR, Core2 events, Intel PMU driver.
[    0.177157] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.177157] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.177157] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.704753] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.706155] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.732523] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.732566] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.736441] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.768344] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.768358] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.768370] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.768379] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.771395] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.598398] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.647780] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    1.652501] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.653874] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.900449] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.073901] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.073903] usbhid: USB HID core driver
inf3rno@inf3rno-EP43T-USB3:~ > dmesg | grep Xorg
inf3rno@inf3rno-EP43T-USB3:~ > dmesg | grep -e error
[    4.148630] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

I have an ACPI PCC probe failed message by booting and I have 3.19 kernel, which I don't really understand. The previous distro on this drive had 3.19 kernel, but I am sure I checked the format drive checkbox by installing the Mint+KDE. I should probably format the drive and install Mint+KDE again.

Comment: What is your monitor model, computer model, and what graphics hardware does your computer have?  How is the monitor connected? Was the resolution working correctly before installing Mint?  Is this your first Linux installation? If not what was the previous distro and did it have the correct resolution?

Comment: @fixer1234 It is working well with Mint 17.2 Cinnamon, Xfce and Mate, so this is something KDE related.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the vivid drivers (the 3.19 kernel was already installed)

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-dev-lts-vivid mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid libglew-dev
```

Somehow that solved the problem. I suspect that something went wrong by the installation of the system, and included parts from the previous system (Mint + Xfce) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal at all: it sounds like you have a problem with the X display manager, possibly a missing driver.

You should search for error messages in `/var/log/Xorg*` (easy to spot: EE is an error, WW is just a warning) and via the command `dmesg`. You may try several different combinations, like

```
   dmesg | grep driver
   dmesg | grep Xorg
   dmesg | grep -e error
```

or just parse the whole kernel ring buffer by visual inspection,

```
   dmesg | less
```

When you find an error message, that will give you some idea of what is going wrong. And, BTW, you do not have an NVIDIA display, do you?

Comment: I have a Geforce GT240 with the nvidia 340.76 driver. Thanks, I'll try.