# KDE Neon can not change screen resolution

Tags: ubuntu, resource-monitor, kde-neon

I recently installed KDE neon on my new PC. And I have a problem. My screen resolution set as 1024 x 768, but I have FHD (1920 x 1080) monitor. And I am not able to change this resolution.
[image]

How can I change my resolution screen properly? Please help

Comment: Check for display driver https://superuser.com/questions/965665/kde-wrong-screen-resolution

Comment: the same problem but have 2 monitors only one is showing images with a low resolution 640x480, KDE neon was working perfectly before the last update and  boot. Windows 10 do is using the 2 monitors without problems.

Comment: @christianbueno.1  I fixed my problem when installed the latest kde neon. It seems  that the necessary drivers for intel hd graphics were not installed.

Answer (score 1):

System: ubuntu 18.04 LTS
In my case, the latest update of NVIDIA ( 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) drivers was the problem. Step to fix the problem:

```
$ sudo apt purge nvidia*
##Now you can reboot, the system will use 
##Nouveau graphic driver(free & open source).
##Or continue to use another nvidia driver version.
##List the recommended nvidia drivers
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
## install for example nvidia-340, you have to realize that there are more
##nvidia versions nvidia-driver-435, nvidia-driver-430, nvidia-driver-418,
##nvidia-384, ##nvidia-375, nvidia-367, etc.
$ sudo apt install nvidia-340
##Reboot the computer.
```

Comment: It could be the solution of problem, but I launched my system without separeted gpu (only integrated in intel cpu) I will vote for this answer but will not apply ot